cannot import name 'create_tool_calling_agent' from 'langchain.agents' too many values to unpack
My code was already working with:
from langchain.agents import create_sql_agent
from langchain.agents import create_sql_agent
agent = create_sql_agent(
                llm=LLM,
                verbose=True,
                toolkit=SQLDatabaseToolkit(db=db, llm=LLM),
                agent_executor_kwargs={'handle_parsing_errors': True})
answer = agent.invoke(agent_prompt)

This was working with no issues and now I suddenly get the error:
cannot import name 'create_tool_calling_agent' from 'langchain.agents' too many values to unpack
after accessing the agent.
Can someone tell me what has changed within Langchain to cause this?
I have tried:
from langchain_community.agent_toolkits import create_sql_agent
as well but get the same error
I do not have anywhere in my code 'create_tool_calling_agent'

Which line is flagged as causing the error, the import or where you call the function to obtain a reference to the agent? It sounds like the latter in which case it would have nothing to do with your import.

it's not very clear what actually causes this error unless you provide executable code. I don't think it's something with the import. And to your question I do not have anywhere in my code 'create_tool_calling_agent', create_tool_calling_agent is a function that's getting internally imported when we call the function create_sql_agent.

it doesnt give me a line where the issue is caused. And this is the executable code, its just an sql agent that goes through a database to find an answer.
